# How to replace certain words in a String?

Tags: java, string, recursion

Note before answering: Don't say I can use regex, split, replace... because I know that, I need to do it specifically this way.

I have the following code in which I attempt to replace the words "for" to 4, "and" to &, "you" to U and "to" to 2. I have to problems with this. One is that I don't know how to create a String object that will always allow me to add upon itself i.e. add more words to it as I go. And the second problem is that the variable "space" (which finds the indexOf " ") equals 0 after the first run through the code, and I cant understand why.

Code:

```
    public static void shorthand(String sentence){
    //if I put String completeSentence; it says the variable might not have been initialized and wont let me run. 

    if (sentence.length() > 0){
        int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");
        String completeSentence = ""; //however if I put this here I just reset my value all the time and cant see the full string after it all adds up.
        if (space == -1){
            if (sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("to")){
                completeSentence += "to";
            } else if(sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("for")){
                completeSentence += "4";
            } else if (sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("you")){
                completeSentence += "you";
            } else if(sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("and")){
                completeSentence += "&";
            } else {
                completeSentence += sentence;
            }
            System.out.println(completeSentence);
        } else {
            String word = sentence.substring(0,space);
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("to")){
                completeSentence += "to";
            } else if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("for")){
                completeSentence += "4";
            } else if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("you")){
                completeSentence += "you";
            } else if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("and")){
                completeSentence += "&";
            } else {
                completeSentence += word;
            }
            shorthand(sentence.substring(space));
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = in.nextLine();
    Functions.shorthand(word);
}
}
```

What can I do to add upon the same string so by the end I can see my full sentence? And also why is my `space = 0` after the first run through the code?

Comment: Why can't you use regex, split or replace?

Comment: Use `StringBuffer`. If you insist on using String, declare completeSentence outside of the loop like this: `String completeSentence = "";`

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen because my teacher said we cant

Comment: @Arkadiy you mean this: `public static void shorthand(String sentence){                                                     String completeSentence = ""; ... }`

Comment: Yes. Just put it where you have a comment that says you have compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

> //if I put String completeSentence; it says the variable might not
>   have been initialized and wont let me run.

That's because you need to give it an initial value, such as:

```
String completeSentence = "";
```

However, using a `StringBuilder` would probably be preferable in this case (even though the compiler will probably try to optimize your current strategy implcitly)

Comment: Alright, but I still get a StackOverFlow error. For Some reason `space = 0` after the first time I run through the code, and it wont change its value.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Why are you doing this recursively? Is that part of the requirement? If you maintain the `StringBuilder` outside of a loop, and then break the original string into chunks (using `indexOf`), do your checks and then append to the `StringBuilder` outside the loop.